# Send params to remote server with FileTransfer() using PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

So I'm creating an iOS app using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), and I need to send extra params to the remote server containing the users id, secret hash, etc with [`FileTransfer()`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer).

From the PhoneGap example on [`FileTransfer()`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer), I see that you can set params, but are they also sent to the remote server? If so, are they sent as `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables? If not, is there a way for me to send params to my remote server with [`FileTransfer()`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)?

```
var params = new Object();
params.value1 = 'test';
params.value2 = 'param';

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imgURI, 'http://example.com/upload', win, fail, options);
```

Comment: @ Josh Foskett did you find any solution then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paramaters are in fact sent as POST variables with `FileTransfer()`.

For example, when I `console.log` the response from FileTransfer(), I get the following:

```
array(2) {
  ["value1"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["value2"]=>
  string(5) "param"
}
```

On my remote server, I used the following PHP code:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
```